# Filter NULL value in 2SXC visual queries

Tags: 2sxc

I am using a tristate to express three different types of information. I a visual query I am able to filter the true and the false states, but i am not able to filter the state null.

Tried something like this:

[Visual Query filter null value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8YTc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found working solution :-)

First I filter all ContentItems that `<Attribute> != False` and than another Filter with `<Attribute> != True` which streams any ContentItem which `<Attribute> == null`

Answer (score 0):

@christian-matyas thanks for answering your own question :)

Best mark it as answered so others can find it too.

If you believe this will be needed often, best open an issue on Github.